# JQuery: How to determine if Slide event is up or down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('a.btn-slide').toggle(function() {
    $("#DivToSlide").slideUp("fast");
    // ...
}, function() {
    $("#DivToSlide").slideDown("fast");
    // ...
});
```

Later in my code, I want to find out if `#DivToSlide` is in either the **up** or **down** position.

How do I do that?

Comment: What if it's in the middle of animating?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Since the `slideDown` function hides the element after it finishes, you can simply check whether the element is visible:

```
if ($('#DivToSlide').is(':visible'))
```

You could also check whether `$('#DivToSlide').height()` is more than some threshold.

Comment: Why should I *"check whether $('#DivToSlide').height() is more than some threshold."*?

Comment: In case it's in the middle of animating.

Comment: Upvoted for the height() trick, I was just looking for a way to do this earlier today.

Comment: Can't you check to make sure it's not `:animated`? Then recheck again if it is? - http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: @fudgey: That depends on what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).next('.nxt_div').height()>1){ }
```

Comment: Sometimes height(), innerHeight(), outerHeight() can return unexpected results as it is based on the current computed values. The answer above negates this issue so would be the better option